# UpdatePanel on web farm with 3 servers

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Im getting an error:

```
Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'ctl00_plhBody_ctrMyPanel_updPanel'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.
```

if one request is sent to server 1 and then after clickin for example a button request is sent to server 2.

How can I get rid of that ?

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: It sounds like your servers don't match.

Comment: Can I do anything about it from code ?

Comment: You can put the same project on all of the servers.

Comment: but I added:  <machineKey
 validationKey="..."
 decryptionKey="..."
 validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>

Comment: You just exposed your keys.  You should change them for security reasons.  I removed them from your comment.

Comment: It sounds like the code files don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You need your load balancer setup with [Persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancer#Persistence) so that requests from one user will stay on the same server.